# I am getting error while running cadence service

Tags: cadence-workflow

I am getting below error after I did docker-compose up

```
cadence_1      | Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.18.0.3:9042': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('172.18.0.3', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
cadence_1      | + echo 'waiting for cassandra to start up'
cadence_1      | + sleep 1
cadence_1      | waiting for cassandra to start up
cadence_1      | + cqlsh --cqlversion=3.4.4 cassandra
cadence_1      | Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.18.0.3:9042': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('172.18.0.3', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
cadence_1      | + echo 'waiting for cassandra to start up'
cadence_1      | + sleep 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pruning your volumes. Execute:

```
docker-compose down
docker volume prune
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thanks @Maxim Fateev, working now, just few minutes back before I read your answer I found this link where you answered the same :) https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/3054